# Scala iteratee to write to a file

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, loops

I have a method `save` that takes an `Iteratee` `it` and saves some data to `it`. Inside the method, the data is available as an [enumerator](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Enumerators) producing byte-array chunks.

```scala
def save[E](consumer: Iteratee[Array[Byte], E]): Future[E] = {
  val producer: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = // ...
  Iteratee.flatten(producer(consumer)).run
}
```

**Wanted:** Call `save` in order to have it write the data to a `FileOutputStream`.

I tried the following but am not sure whether this is the way to go:

```scala
def writeToStream(s: OutputStream) =
  Iteratee.foreach((e: Array[Byte]) => s.write(e)).
    mapDone(r => { s.close(); r })
save(writeToStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile)))
```

**Question:** Is this the way it's supposed to be done? I fear that this will not always close the stream (case of exceptions).

I am using the Play Framework Iteratee library from [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org) 2.1 (which uses Scala futures).

Answer (score 1):

The scaladocs for Iteratee say that it is in the responsibility of the "producer" not the iteratee to handle resources:

> The Iteratee does not do any resource management (such as closing streams); the producer pushing stuff into the Iteratee has that responsibility.

You might be successful using the "onDoneEnumerating" method in Enumerator to clean up resources afterwards.

[Scaladoc Iteratee](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee)